# Vaadin + Highcharts: The generated SVG width is always 100% in gridLayout with 2 columns

Tags: svg, highcharts, vaadin, grid-layout

In Vaadin UI, I have a `gridLayout` with `setColumns(2)` : having 2 columns.

I add 2 highcharts component to the first row: one at column 0, and the other at column 1.

The 2 highcharts are only displayed a half (see the 1st screenshot)
The width of 2 SVG of 2 highcharts is 100% of the browser windows width instead of 50%.

[image]

But if I resize the windows browser, the SVG width is 50% as expected (see the 2nd screenshot).

[image]

The problem is only when I use `gridLayout`. It's ok if I use `horizontalLayout`.

Anyone has a solution for this problem? Thanks.

See the html code:
[image]

Comment: Does it happen only for SVG images?

Comment: The <div class="graph"> has the width 802px.  But <div class="highcharts-container vaadin-chart"> and the SVG have the width 1616px. See the 3rd screenshot

Comment: Can't reproduce this error at least on Firefox, and Vaadin 7.5 using highcharts. It always works as expected. See: http://pastebin.com/rpt0tcxq

Comment: Consider using [`chart.reflow()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow) after rendering. Maybe you render chart in a hidden div or something similar.

Comment: How do you define the size of the Chart in your code and what's the size of the GridLayout in your code?

Comment: Sorry for the vacation. The mainLayout takes 100% width and height. 
mainLayout contains a tabsheet taking 100% width and height.
Each tab of tabsheet takes 100% width and height.
Each tab contains a GridLayout taking 100% width and "-1px" height.
The GridLayout has 2 columns. And I try to add a graph (100% width and 300px height) to gridLayout.